# Can we Use JSOM in Provider Hosted App for accessing data in App Web?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am working on Provider Hosted App, which will fetch data from App Web.

When I tried using Rest Api with Request Executor I am able to fetch data from AppWeb. but when I tried to use JSOM I am getting "UnHandle Exception from Server" error.

So Can we use JSOM to Access App web or not, if so how to do?

Answer (score 0):

We can access App web data from Provider Hosted Apps using cross domain library using SP.AppContextSite,

PFB Same code for same

[image]